# Sumifs #ref error in google sheet - unexplainable

Tags: google-sheets, ref, sumifs

I have this very strange error which makes no sense to me.

I am using below formula to sum up sales values based on 2 criteria (one being month and the other one category)

```
=sumifs(Sales!$S:$S,Sales!$H:$H,D3,Sales!$Q:$Q,$A$12)
```

This formula works absolutely fine if I set cell D3 to 52020 (i.e. sum up all sales for may) - however, if I change the value to 62020 I am getting a ref error (same if I enter the value directly into the formula rather than using a cell). I tried other values and it looks like that only 62020 produces an error.

There are sales with 62020. In any case, this makes absolutely no sense to me especially given the error seems to come due to a Criteria not a range/ref.

I wonder if this is a bug (but probably I am missing something). Any ideas?

Comment: Please share a test sheet

Answer (score 1):

could be that for some reason your sheets converts it to date

```
62020 = 10/19/2069
```

try:

```
=INDEX(SUMIFS(Sales!S:S, Sales!H:H*1, D3*1, Sales!Q:Q, A12))
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried it and behaviour is exactly the same. I mean it's no biggy, I will just manually add up the figures end of the month for this month (as the formula works again with 72020). Is just super bizzar (I have tried to change format or the cell, etc.).

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?